# Wrong octane fuel

Tags: gasoline, octane

I have a 2014 Fiat Punto and have been using 92 octane gas. I have never read the manual, but am now told I should use 95. Should I use what is in the tank before filling with 95 or is it OK to mix them.

Comment: Either is fine.

Answer (score 26):

It's not a problem mixing them. Just start using 95 if that is what the engine calls for. You'll not create any issues doing so.

Modern day engines have sensors which can adjust for the fuel. If yours calls for 95, but you're running 92, the engine most likely won't be putting out the power it would on the 95. You probably won't notice a difference in driving, but you might. Anyway, its nothing really to worry about  mixing the two.

Answer (score 11):

Presumably since you say "92 octane gas" you are not in Europe.

The whole topic is a mess, because there are different scales for measuring "octane". The most common scale world-wide is RON, but there is a different scale known as MON which produces lower numbers, and in some countries (particularly the USA, Canada, and Brazil) the numbers on the pump are actually the average between RON and MON. The MON number can be as much as 8 points lower than the RON for some fuels.

The Punto was designed in Europe, and none of this is an issue there, because grade are always described in RON and the cheapest "regular" gasoline grade available almost everywhere is 95. If lower RON grades are on sale they are sometimes *more* expensive than 95 because of the small demand for them. For example a typical UK gas station sells "premium" 95 ROM ("premium" being marketing-speak for "lowest grade", of course) and "super" 97, and possibly a higher grade (e.g. 99, 100, or 102) with a brand name from a particular oil company (Shell, BP, etc).

Comment: About 92 not being available in Europe: Denmark, Ukraine and Moldova still had it available a while back and Belarus still had 93 around that time. Not sure if they still do, but that was less than a decade ago.

Comment: "and in some countries (particularly the USA, Canada, and Brazil) the numbers on the pump are actually the average between RON and MON." At least in the USA, this is explicitly stated at the pump, too. ((R+N)/2 and all)

Comment: I've seen that "102" thing here and there and it never made sense to me - isn't it just a percentage of one chemical to another?  How can a percentage possibly be higher than 100%?  Sounds like a marketing scam to me...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman LPG has a RON of 108 - its not a percentage.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, octane rating is a measure of how much compression it takes to ignite the fuel.  It's on a linear scale, with pure heptane having an octane rating of 0, and pure iso-octane having an octane rating of 100.  Something even more resistant to compression-induced ignition than iso-octane, quite reasonably, is described as having an octane rating above 100.

Comment: Wait you can get higher than 98?? In Australia you get 91, 95 and 98. I've never seen anything else.

Comment: @Clonkex 102 is for tuned cars, you can see it near circuits for track days. Most normal gas stations won't sell it, but in the Netherlands and UK there's at least a couple of places that do. Perhaps race cars use something similar as well, I don't know.

Comment: @Clonkex In Germany, Aral offers 102 octane gas at all (most?) service stations.

Comment: @Clonkex Yes, by having a knock resistance higher than that. Pure isooctane and toluene comes to mind.

Comment: The 95 recommendation is RON. Your "92 octane" gas, if bought in the US, is probably around 95 RON.

Comment: Uh, no I think they're definitely in Europe.  A Fiat Punto doesn't need performance fuel.  Euro 95 (RON) is like US 89 (AKI/PON), so mid-grade (in the US, closer to standard grade in EU).  OP was using Euro 92, I'd guess, which is like US 87 (basic grade).  Newer cars, even small ones, are using more forced induction and can need slightly higher octane fuel, but US 95 AKI/PON is performance fuel, equivalent to ~100 RON (in Europe), and that definitely doesn't go into an economy hatchback.

Comment: @winny I knew it was possible, but I didn't think anyone sold higher octane.

Comment: @Clonkex, if you want to see something higher than 98 octane, go to your local small airport.  The FBO there will almost certainly have some variety of 100 octane fuel, and possibly 110 octane.  (Note that in most of the world, avgas still uses tetraethyl lead, so don't go putting it in your car's gas tank.)

Comment: @Mark That said, leaded avgas is disappearing fast.  Expect it gone within a few years - phaseout plans started over a decade ago.

Comment: @Mark Ah true, I actually did know that. Forgot about aviation fuel.

Comment: Taken to a silly extreme, diesel fuel would have an RON of several hundred (and of course, it won't ignite in a petrol engine at all! ) It has its own "cetane" scale, but diesels are in general less fussy about the hydrocarbon they are burning. Fuel lubricity, that's a completely different story.

Answer (score 5):

A modern car (say, post-1995) will run on lower octane gasoline with reduced performance (power, economy) and no other issues.

Older cars did a lot of nasty things ranging from occasional "pinging" or "ringing" noise and accellerated engine wear to complete engine failure.

Then again, one cannot easily find these days neither a pre-1995 car nor a gasoline with low enough octane number in order to create problems in a car built for pre-1995 standards gasoline.

p.s. it is OK and pretty much advisable to mix some '95 gasoline into '92 in your tank

Comment: 1995 also happens to be roughly where cars tend to handle bio-fuel-added petrol (like 95 E10) better. Between '95 and '09 how cars handled fuel got even more complex, to a point it would surprise me the Punto cares much about the difference between 92 and 95 octane. Performance suffers a bit, sure, but near-empty it's going to drive just fine. Wasn't a fast car to start with.

Comment: _one cannot easily find these days neither a pre-1995 car_ - I have to disagree. I'm in the UK and see pre-95 cars all the time. On my street alone (about 60 houses) there are 3 pre-95 cars (A-reg, F-reg and M-reg).

Comment: @AleksG in absolute sense, yes. I'm in Bulgaria and I pretty much own two cars that are 1982 and one that is exactly 1995 so on my street alone (about 100 houses) they are at least 3. Then again, most pre-1995 cars today are either unpleasant to use, expensive to own, or both, so you need a good reason to own one. (Well, the reason may be that you are poor and in a desperate need of a car.) What's that "A-reg, F-reg, M-reg" ?

Comment: @fraxinus In UK, for cars registered between 1983 and first half of 2001, the first letter of the registration indicates the year - A is mid-1983 to mid-84, F is mid-1988 to mid-89 and M is mid-1994 to mid-95. These cars are all owned by fairly old people who probably bought them as new.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Our (and other that I am aware of) registrations are region-based.